# Error: not all arguments converted during string formatting for dd/mm/yyy

Tags: python

beginner python user here.
I need to validate a date string without using the datetime() module.
(hopefully, you can see) the year needs to be greater than 2021, and the date needs to be a valid date including leap years.
So far I have this:

```
while True:  
Date = input('enter date of appointment in dd/mm/yyyy format. ')
day,month,year = Date.split('/')

if month=={1,3,5,7,8,10,12}:
    max_days=31
elif month=={4,6,9,11}:
    max_days=30
elif year%4==0 and year%100!=0 or year%400==0:
    max_days=29
else:
    max_days=28

if month<1 or month>12:
    print('invalid, enter a number between 1 - 12')
elif day<1 or day>max_days:
    print('invalid, check day')
elif year<2022:
    print('invalid, enter a year greater than 2021')
else:
    break
```

But I'm getting the error: "not all arguments converted during string formatting" on line 10 which is  "elif year%4==0 and year%100!=0 or year%400==0:"

I'm confused as to how to fix it, am I missing another formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The day, month and year variables are strings. This means that the when %-operator is used, the string will be interpreted as a format string. But as the strings aren't format strings, it will result in an error.

The solution is to convert the day, month and year variables to an integer.

```
day_string, month_string, year_string = Date.split('/')
day = int(day_string)
month = int(month_string)
year = int(year_string)
```

Also in the if statements where you check the maximal day count based on the month, you use `if month == {1,3,5,7,8,10,12}:` this won't check if the month variable is 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10 or 12. To fix this other issue use `if month in [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]`.

Comment: alternatively, you can just use `map`, like so: `day,month,year = map(int, Date.split('/'))`

Answer (score 0):

Your variables `day`, `month` and `year` resulting from the `Date.split('/')~ are` string`s not` int`

Try the following:

```
while True:  
  Date = input('enter date of appointment in dd/mm/yyyy format. ')
  day,month,year = Date.split('/')

  if int(month)=={1,3,5,7,8,10,12}:
    max_days=31
  elif int(month)=={4,6,9,11}:
    max_days=30
  elif int(year)%4==0 and int(year)%100!=0 or int(year)%400==0:
    max_days=29
  else:
    max_days=28

  if int(month)<1 or int(month)>12:
    print('invalid, enter a number between 1 - 12')
  elif int(day)<1 or int(day)>max_days:
    print('invalid, check day')
  elif int(year)<2022:
    print('invalid, enter a year greater than 2021')
  else:
    break
```